# Amazon S3 and UNC paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, unc

I'm experimenting with Amazon AWS S3. The documentation contains a lot of information about URLs to make buckets available, but I'm having a hard time to find information how to setup UNC paths. Some of our applications need UNC paths to read and write files during batch processes.
Has anyone information how to setup UNC paths to a S3 bucket or folder in a S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *you can't*. S3 is Object storage; as opposed to EBS, which is block storage. It is for a reason... S3 has "eventual consistency", which means that you can't read the data immediately after write.

If you understand the limitations, there are good cheap products from S3 Browser and Cloudberry that will allow you to map S3 bucket to your computer. You can then use UNC the way you use any other drive

Comment: Thank you Felix. It sounds like a lot of tools can add some more connectors to be able to use AWS tools. I'm currently looking into http://aws.amazon.com/cli/. I would like to avoid having to rely on a local tool that maps UNC paths in our production environment.

Comment: I think this answer is now out of date: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/aws-storage-gateway-adds-smb-support-to-store-objects-in-amazon-s3/